Anaconda Navigator Backup on Mac OS is not working on Windows
I have a backup from my anaconda navigator environment on mac but when I'm importing it on windows its not working and showing the error that packages not found:
name: university_web_scraping
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - anyio=4.2.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - appnope=0.1.2=py310hecd8cb5_1001
  - argon2-cffi=21.3.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - argon2-cffi-bindings=21.2.0=py310hca72f7f_0
  - asttokens=2.0.5=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - async-lru=2.0.4=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - attrs=23.1.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - babel=2.11.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - beautifulsoup4=4.12.2=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - blas=1.0=mkl
  - bleach=4.1.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - bottleneck=1.3.7=py310h7b7cdfe_0
  - bzip2=1.0.8=h6c40b1e_6
  - ca-certificates=2024.3.11=hecd8cb5_0
  - certifi=2024.2.2=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - cffi=1.16.0=py310h6c40b1e_1
  - charset-normalizer=2.0.4=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - chart-studio=1.1.0=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - comm=0.2.1=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - debugpy=1.6.7=py310hcec6c5f_0
  - decorator=5.1.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defusedxml=0.7.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - exceptiongroup=1.2.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - executing=0.8.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - html5lib=1.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - icu=73.1=hcec6c5f_0
  - idna=3.7=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - intel-openmp=2023.1.0=ha357a0b_43548
  - ipykernel=6.28.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - ipython=8.20.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - jedi=0.18.1=py310hecd8cb5_1
  - jinja2=3.1.3=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - json5=0.9.6=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - jsonschema=4.19.2=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - jsonschema-specifications=2023.7.1=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - jupyter-lsp=2.2.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - jupyter_client=8.6.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - jupyter_core=5.5.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - jupyter_events=0.8.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - jupyter_server=2.10.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - jupyter_server_terminals=0.4.4=py310hecd8cb5_1
  - jupyterlab=4.0.11=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - jupyterlab_pygments=0.1.2=py_0
  - jupyterlab_server=2.25.1=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - libcxx=14.0.6=h9765a3e_0
  - libffi=3.4.4=hecd8cb5_1
  - libiconv=1.16=h6c40b1e_3
  - libsodium=1.0.18=h1de35cc_0
  - libxml2=2.10.4=h45904e2_2
  - libxslt=1.1.37=h6c40b1e_1
  - lxml=5.2.1=py310h946e0e5_0
  - markupsafe=2.1.3=py310h6c40b1e_0
  - matplotlib-inline=0.1.6=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - mechanize=0.4.10=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - mistune=2.0.4=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - mkl=2023.1.0=h8e150cf_43560
  - mkl-service=2.4.0=py310h6c40b1e_1
  - mkl_fft=1.3.8=py310h6c40b1e_0
  - mkl_random=1.2.4=py310ha357a0b_0
  - nbclient=0.8.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - nbconvert=7.10.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - nbformat=5.9.2=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - ncurses=6.4=hcec6c5f_0
  - nest-asyncio=1.6.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - notebook=7.0.8=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - notebook-shim=0.2.3=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - numexpr=2.8.7=py310h827a554_0
  - numpy=1.26.4=py310h827a554_0
  - numpy-base=1.26.4=py310ha186be2_0
  - openssl=3.0.13=hca72f7f_1
  - overrides=7.4.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - packaging=23.2=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - pandas=2.2.1=py310hcec6c5f_0
  - pandocfilters=1.5.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - parso=0.8.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - pexpect=4.8.0=pyhd3eb1b0_3
  - pip=24.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - platformdirs=3.10.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - plotly=5.19.0=py310h20db666_0
  - prometheus_client=0.14.1=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - prompt-toolkit=3.0.43=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - prompt_toolkit=3.0.43=hd3eb1b0_0
  - psutil=5.9.0=py310hca72f7f_0
  - ptyprocess=0.7.0=pyhd3eb1b0_2
  - pure_eval=0.2.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - pycparser=2.21=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - pygments=2.15.1=py310hecd8cb5_1
  - python=3.10.14=h5ee71fb_1
  - python-dateutil=2.9.0post0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - python-fastjsonschema=2.16.2=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - python-json-logger=2.0.7=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - python-tzdata=2023.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - pytz=2024.1=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - pyyaml=6.0.1=py310h6c40b1e_0
  - pyzmq=25.1.2=py310hcec6c5f_0
  - readline=8.2=hca72f7f_0
  - referencing=0.30.2=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - requests=2.31.0=py310hecd8cb5_1
  - retrying=1.3.3=pyhd3eb1b0_2
  - rfc3339-validator=0.1.4=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - rfc3986-validator=0.1.1=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - rpds-py=0.10.6=py310hf2ad997_0
  - send2trash=1.8.2=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - setuptools=69.5.1=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - six=1.16.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - sniffio=1.3.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - soupsieve=2.5=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - sqlite=3.45.3=h6c40b1e_0
  - stack_data=0.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - tbb=2021.8.0=ha357a0b_0
  - tenacity=8.2.2=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - terminado=0.17.1=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - tinycss2=1.2.1=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - tk=8.6.14=h4d00af3_0
  - tomli=2.0.1=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - tornado=6.3.3=py310h6c40b1e_0
  - traitlets=5.7.1=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - typing-extensions=4.11.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - typing_extensions=4.11.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - tzdata=2024a=h04d1e81_0
  - urllib3=2.1.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - wcwidth=0.2.5=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - webencodings=0.5.1=py310hecd8cb5_1
  - websocket-client=0.58.0=py310hecd8cb5_4
  - wheel=0.43.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - xz=5.4.6=h6c40b1e_1
  - yaml=0.2.5=haf1e3a3_0
  - zeromq=4.3.5=hcec6c5f_0

The Error:
Channels:
 - conda-forge
 - defaults
Platform: win-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - zeromq==4.3.5=hcec6c5f_0
  - yaml==0.2.5=haf1e3a3_0
  - xz==5.4.6=h6c40b1e_1
  - wheel==0.43.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - websocket-client==0.58.0=py310hecd8cb5_4
  - webencodings==0.5.1=py310hecd8cb5_1
  - urllib3==2.1.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - typing_extensions==4.11.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - typing-extensions==4.11.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - traitlets==5.7.1=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - tornado==6.3.3=py310h6c40b1e_0
  - tomli==2.0.1=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - tk==8.6.14=h4d00af3_0
  - tinycss2==1.2.1=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - terminado==0.17.1=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - tenacity==8.2.2=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - tbb==2021.8.0=ha357a0b_0
  - sqlite==3.45.3=h6c40b1e_0
  - soupsieve==2.5=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - sniffio==1.3.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - setuptools==69.5.1=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - send2trash==1.8.2=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - rpds-py==0.10.6=py310hf2ad997_0
  - rfc3986-validator==0.1.1=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - rfc3339-validator==0.1.4=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - requests==2.31.0=py310hecd8cb5_1
  - referencing==0.30.2=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - readline==8.2=hca72f7f_0
  - pyzmq==25.1.2=py310hcec6c5f_0
  - pyyaml==6.0.1=py310h6c40b1e_0
  - pytz==2024.1=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - python-json-logger==2.0.7=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - python-fastjsonschema==2.16.2=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - python-dateutil==2.9.0post0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - python==3.10.14=h5ee71fb_1
  - pygments==2.15.1=py310hecd8cb5_1
  - psutil==5.9.0=py310hca72f7f_0
  - prompt-toolkit==3.0.43=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - prometheus_client==0.14.1=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - plotly==5.19.0=py310h20db666_0
  - platformdirs==3.10.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - pip==24.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - pandas==2.2.1=py310hcec6c5f_0
  - packaging==23.2=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - overrides==7.4.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - openssl==3.0.13=hca72f7f_1
  - numpy-base==1.26.4=py310ha186be2_0
  - numpy==1.26.4=py310h827a554_0
  - numexpr==2.8.7=py310h827a554_0
  - notebook-shim==0.2.3=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - notebook==7.0.8=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - nest-asyncio==1.6.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - ncurses==6.4=hcec6c5f_0
  - nbformat==5.9.2=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - nbconvert==7.10.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - nbclient==0.8.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - mkl_random==1.2.4=py310ha357a0b_0
  - mkl_fft==1.3.8=py310h6c40b1e_0
  - mkl-service==2.4.0=py310h6c40b1e_1
  - mkl==2023.1.0=h8e150cf_43560
  - mistune==2.0.4=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - matplotlib-inline==0.1.6=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - markupsafe==2.1.3=py310h6c40b1e_0
  - lxml==5.2.1=py310h946e0e5_0
  - libxslt==1.1.37=h6c40b1e_1
  - libxml2==2.10.4=h45904e2_2
  - libsodium==1.0.18=h1de35cc_0
  - libiconv==1.16=h6c40b1e_3
  - libffi==3.4.4=hecd8cb5_1
  - libcxx==14.0.6=h9765a3e_0
  - jupyterlab_server==2.25.1=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - jupyterlab==4.0.11=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - jupyter_server_terminals==0.4.4=py310hecd8cb5_1
  - jupyter_server==2.10.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - jupyter_events==0.8.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - jupyter_core==5.5.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - jupyter_client==8.6.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - jupyter-lsp==2.2.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - jsonschema-specifications==2023.7.1=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - jsonschema==4.19.2=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - jinja2==3.1.3=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - jedi==0.18.1=py310hecd8cb5_1
  - ipython==8.20.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - ipykernel==6.28.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - intel-openmp==2023.1.0=ha357a0b_43548
  - idna==3.7=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - icu==73.1=hcec6c5f_0
  - exceptiongroup==1.2.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - debugpy==1.6.7=py310hcec6c5f_0
  - comm==0.2.1=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - cffi==1.16.0=py310h6c40b1e_1
  - certifi==2024.2.2=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - ca-certificates==2024.3.11=hecd8cb5_0
  - bzip2==1.0.8=h6c40b1e_6
  - bottleneck==1.3.7=py310h7b7cdfe_0
  - beautifulsoup4==4.12.2=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - babel==2.11.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - attrs==23.1.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - async-lru==2.0.4=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - argon2-cffi-bindings==21.2.0=py310hca72f7f_0
  - appnope==0.1.2=py310hecd8cb5_1001
  - anyio==4.2.0=py310hecd8cb5_0

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.


I just read this https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html there is a section on creating similar environments.
So packages across platforms might have different version dependencies.
Your best bet is to just lock in the versions of the packages you care about.
You could also try using pip freeze instead while the environment is activated.
The answer here has a really good explanation.
How to share conda environments across platforms

My first question is why it adding another = equal sign if it will not work. so is there any way to backup without these details. and also after deleting the second equal sign it still show error for 4 packages:
`PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

readline=8.2*
ncurses=6.5*
libcxx=14.0.6*
appnope=0.1.2*
`


I have tried doing what you wanted before and I just gave up selected versions for packages I cared about like numpy and pandas. But take a look at my answer again, it may help.
